# Converting latitude/longitude pairs into gridded Web Mercator GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a set of data that is essentially an array of coordinates (WGS84) and values.

Example:

> 51.5834,-101.1709,0.0452,51.5834,-101.1567,0.0648,51.5834,-101.1425,0.0339,51.5924,-101.2133,0.0339,51.5924,-101.1992,0.0365

This data values are ~1.079km apart. Since it is approximate gdal_translate cannot be used.

I would like to convert this data into a GeoTIFF that is projected into Web Mercator. I understand that some sort of gridding will have to occur.

I believe the current system is using the dimensions of pixels (at zoom level 8) as a sort of gridding system. I may not be 100% correct as reading C++ code (especially this code) is very confusing.

It calculates what pixel the latitude/longitude will intersect and applies the value there and somehow applies that to the GeoTIFF, which is then used to output tiles (using a Gdal2Tiles script)

However, I would like to do this with the standard GDAL tooling rather then some custom C++ code.

Is this possible? Basically taking a latitude/longitude/value CSV and converting that to a gridded Web Mercator GeoTIFF?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to *interpolate* a raster based on your point data. I don't know the specific steps for doing that in C++ with GDAL, but this blog post might help: https://jacintoestima.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/idw-interpolation-from-csv-using-gdal/